# Where do I edit to change the search results design?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have created a simple search engine who gets data from a PHP table and post the results. But as of right now it posts the results in a single line and nothing to show that they're in fact 4 different columns. What I'm looking for is a way to create a table so it looks more presentable. I have the search engine divided into 2 .php files.

1st file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
include('system_admin.inc.php');
$title = 'Leonard';
make_header($title,array('enable_ajax' => true));


?>

<html>


<head>
<title>Leonard</title>
<script type=text/javascript src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript ">



function searchq() {
var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();

$.post("testsearch.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function(output) {
    $("#output") .html(output);






});

}
</script>

</head>


<body>
<h1>Search</h1>


<form class="odd" action="leonard.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" onkeyup="searchq();" />


    <div id="output">

</div>

</form>





</body>
</html>
```

2nd file:

```
mysql_connect ("localhost","root","xxxxxx") or die ("Connectionissues");
mysql_select_db ("xxxxxx") or die("Can't find DB");
$output = '';

if(isset($_POST['searchVal']))  {
    $searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
    $searchq = preg_replace ("#^0-9#"," ",$searchq);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ds_OrderItem WHERE idProduct LIKE '%$searchq%' LIMIT 100") or die("Search invalid!");
    $count = mysql_num_rows ($query);

    if($count == 0){
        $output = 'Order have never been made before';




}else{


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

         $idproduct = $row['idProduct'];
         $idorder = $row['idOrder'];
         $title = $row['title'];
         $qty = $row['qty'];


        $output .= '<div> '.$idproduct.' '.$idorder.' '.$title.' '.$qty.' </div>';

        }   




  if($_POST['searchVal'] == NULL) {
            $output = "";
        }

    }

}
```

I want these four columns to be displayed in a presentable manner:

```
$idproduct = $row['idProduct'];
$idorder = $row['idOrder'];
$title = $row['title'];
$qty = $row['qty'];
```

Can anyone help me with this? :-)

Thanks in advance for reading and any advice given!

Comment: can  you please share the image of output

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/v0OPU) @BachchaSingh

Comment: image not showing

Comment: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/upihhKL.png) @BachchaSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this portion

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

         $idproduct = $row['idProduct'];
         $idorder = $row['idOrder'];
         $title = $row['title'];
         $qty = $row['qty'];


        $output .= '<div> '.$idproduct.' '.$idorder.' '.$title.' '.$qty.' </div>';

        }
```

to

```
$output .='<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$output .= '<tr><td>'.$row['idProduct'].'</td><td>'.$row['idOrder'].'</td><td>'.$row['title'].'</td><td>'.$row['qty'].'</td></tr>';
}   
$output .='</table>';
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This made it into 4 seperate columns! Now, is there any easy way to make a border or to title each column?

Comment: yes you can do this by changing $output .='<table>';

Comment: use this 
$output .='<table  border="1"><tr><td>Product</td><td>Order</td><td>Title</td><td>Qty</td></tr>';

Comment: Thank you very much Bachcha! Saving angel!